Error messages when I tried to brms::brm() in RStudio (under rstan and macrtools)
So I'm trying to run a Bayesian Model in RStudio using brm(), which required a C++ compiler (macrtools and rstan) but when I have everything installed and tried to run it only returned very long error messages. And yes I have tried uninstalling. I ran into pretty similar error messages when I tried to run brm() and when I was checking for rstan installation using this code:
example(stan_model, package = "rstan", run.dontrun = TRUE)
Below are my latest error messages:
Compiling Stan program...
Warning in system2(file.path(R.home(component = "bin"), "R"), args = "CMD config CXX17",  :
  running command ''/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R' CMD config CXX17 2>/dev/null' had status 2
Warning in .fun(model_code = .x1) :
  C++ compiler not found on system. If absent, see
 https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/wiki/RStan-Getting-Started
...
/Users/myname/.R/Makevars:1: *** missing separator.  Stop.
Error in compileCode(f, code, language = language, verbose = verbose) : 
  /Users/myname/.R/Makevars:1: *** missing separator.  Stop.
Error in if (nzchar(cxx)) { : argument is of length zero
Calls: <Anonymous> -> .shlib_internal
In addition: Warning message:
In system(paste(MAKE, p1(paste("-f", shQuote(makefiles))), "compilers"),  :
  running command 'make -f '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/etc/Makeconf' -f '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/share/make/shlib.mk' -f '/Users/myname/.R/Makevars' compilers' had status 2
Execution halted
Error in sink(type = "output") : invalid connection

MacOS 15.1.1 / Rstudio 4.4.2 / Apple clang version 16.0.0
This is the setup I'm using and I'll explain what I did to get here
I started off with the r-macos-rtools via the installer not realising we're not using the installation package anymore, so I downloaded this latest version (but didn't run anything because soon afterwards I discovered the correct way which is via the macrtools R package. This could be a potential cause because I'm not sure that I have properly removed everything that I have downloaded from this installer.
As I'm running codes on macrtools, following the steps on their website, I first encountered errors ending with cmath file not found when I tried to download "RcppEigen" (also present when checking rstan and running brm). So I played around with nano ~/.R/Makevars in my terminal, which did solve my problem with downloading RcppEigen, but lead me to errors ending with math.h file not found, some further playing around with Makevars (at some point I also installed brew) now lead to me to C++ compiler not found on system (I swear I have everything installed). Now this is what my Makevars in the terminal look like:
chmod u+rw ~/.R/Makevars
chmod u+rwx ~/.R

CC = clang
CXX = clang++
CXXFLAGS = -isysroot $(xcrun --show-sdk-path) -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++17

LDFLAGS = -L/usr/local/lib
CPPFLAGS = -I/usr/local/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include

        SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS += -Wl,-rpath,${R_HOME}/lib ${R_HOME}/lib/libc++abi.1.dylib
        SSHLIB_CXX14LDFLAGS += -Wl,-rpath,${R_HOME}/lib ${R_HOME}/lib/libc++abi.1.dylib

I terminated my terminal and 'nano ~/.R/Makevars' now this is the warning message I'm getting:
/Users/myname/.R/Makevars:1: *** missing separator.  Stop.
Error in compileCode(f, code, language = language, verbose = verbose) : 
  /Users/myname/.R/Makevars:1: *** missing separator.  Stop.
Error in if (nzchar(cxx)) { : argument is of length zero
Calls: <Anonymous> -> .shlib_internal
In addition: Warning message:
In system(paste(MAKE, p1(paste("-f", shQuote(makefiles))), "compilers"),  :
  running command 'make -f '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/etc/Makeconf' -f '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/share/make/shlib.mk' -f '/Users/myname/.R/Makevars' compilers' had status 2
Execution halted
Error in sink(type = "output") : invalid connection

I just wanted to run Bayesian models in R but I felt like I got too carried away. Am I cooked?
